# How to create a texture / matte finish

Tags: texture

I'm new to graphic design, so forgive me.

Does anyone know how to create a the matte/texture feature that appears on the twitter start page when a user is logged out? Its like a light blue which has been altered.

https://twitter.com/?lang=en&logged_out=1#

I'm not interested in the map images, just how to select a color and give it that sort of texture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit lengthy, but not too difficult.

### Part 1: Creating the Pattern

1. **Create new file in Photoshop**. Go to `File` > `New...` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, enter the values of `200px` for `Width` and `Height`. *Until otherwise indicated, we are working in this file.*

   [image: Create new file in Photoshop]
2. **Fill the background with black**. You can do this by pressing the <kbd>D</kbd> key to reset the selected foreground and background colors to black and white and then using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on Mac to fill the whole canvas. You should now see a canvas filled with all black.

   [image: Fill the background with black]
3. **Add noise**. Go to `Filters` > `Noise` > `Add Noise...` and wait for `Add Noise` dialog box to appear. Set the `Amount` to approximately `100%`. `Distribution` option does not matter (I used `Gaussian`). Check the `Monochrome` checkbox if it is available and click the `OK` button.

   [image: Add noise]
4. At this point canvas should display a grainy black & white pattern, more black than white. If you have more white than black, go back through the earlier steps and make sure you did everything precisely.

   [image: State of the document at this stage]
5. **Define this image as a pattern**. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Mac to select the entire canvas, then go to `Edit` > `Define Pattern…`, and wait for `Pattern Name` dialog box to appear. You can enter whatever name you like, such as `Grainy Texture` for example.

   [image: Define this image as a pattern]

You now have a pattern defined that you can use anytime when working in Photoshop. Let’s use it to create the blue texture like on the Twitter homepage.

### Part 2: Creating the Effect Using the Pattern

1. **Create new file in Photoshop**. Enter your values for `Width` and `Height` (I used `900px` and `800px` respectively). *We are now working in this file, not the Texture File.*

   [image: Create new file in Photoshop]
2. **Fill the background with blue-gray**. Left-click on the foreground color swatch at the bottom of the `Tools` Panel and wait for `Color Picker (Foreground Color)` dialog box to appear. Enter `51708a` as a value for the HEX text field (you will find it near the bottom-right, with a hash sign `#` beside it). This value represents a blue-gray color similar to what Twitter is using, and the picker should display that color after you type in that text. Click `OK` in the dialog box and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on Mac to fill the current layer with this blue-gray color.

   [image: Fill the background with blue-gray]
3. **Create a `Pattern Fill` layer with previously created pattern**. Go to `Layer` > `New Fill Layer` > `Pattern…`, wait for the `New Layer` dialog box to appear, enter `Texture (matte)` in the `Name` field and click `OK`.

   [image: New Layer dialog box]

   Wait for the `Pattern Fill` dialog box to appear and make sure previously created pattern is selected. If not, click the down arrow near the preview of the pattern and choose `Grainy Texture` (you can mouse-over the patterns to see their names in the tooltip).

   [image: Pattern Fill dialog box]
4. **Lower opacity and change blend mode to `Overlay` for texture layer**. In the `Layers` Panel, you should see a menu option that says `Normal`. You will need to click this and change it to `Overlay` and also set the `Opacity` to approximately `3%`.

   [image: Lower opacity and change blend mode for texture layer]

And that’s it. You are done:

[image: Final result]

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!