# How to create matte black paper on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, black, paper

I want to mock up the paper texture seen [here](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/436497388857446834/), but I can't find any proper tutorial or link on it. Would anybody know how to get this done?

I tried [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/)… As well as [this](http://paperheartcamera.blogspot.in/2012/06/)… and a few others on youtube about Matte effect on Photos But the first one just gave me a roughish texture, and the second one made it a little Instagramish. I'm new to PS and am probably doing it wrong.

Samples in comments. My reputation doesn't allow me to post more than one link

Comment: Yes, yes I would. Bet others do to. But I'm not telling unless you show some effort. What have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: Well fair enough. I tried http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/how-to-create-a-texture-matte-finish

As well as http://paperheartcamera.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-create-matte-effect-in-photoshop.html and a few others on youtube about Matte effect on Photos

But the first one just gave me a roughish texture, and the second one made it a little Instagramish. I'm new to PS and am probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Post a picture of your best attempt and what you don't like about it. It'll be easier for us to help you from that point then write up an entirely new tutorial, just for you, that might also not get the exact results you're after.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gaxK8rZ.jpg

Here's the texture I managed to create. I have a feeling that its not working out because the background color is black instead of other colors. If I try with Blue or Green, I get better (not optimal) results: http://i.imgur.com/rj26tBq.jpg

Comment: It's going to be hard to recreate it without lighting and perspective. The one you posted in your question has almost no texture and is mostly lighting. And by lighting I mean gradient

Comment: @ChanandlerBong You should include your efforts in the question itself :)

Comment: @MarkMussler - Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do...

Simple black document and run `Filter > Noise > Add Noise` to create some texture....

[image]

It's subtle, but there.

Then use `Layer > layer Style > Gradient Overlay` to apply a radial gradient set to screen to brighten the center. Again, it's meant to be subtle.

[image]

If the noise is too harsh, I'd add a new solid black layer above and reduce its opacity.

[image]

Now highlight all layers and use  `Layer > Smart Objects > Convert to Smart Object`.

From there you transform the Smart Object to the shape and angle you want.... And you can add any additional items if needed, like the green shape below. (green shape is actually set to 80% opacity so the texture of the noise shows through it a bit.)

[image]

I'd then group it all, and add a new gradient overlay layer style to the group to reflect some more subtle lighting.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*I originally posted this as a comment, but I decided to elaborate and create an answer:*

You're going to achieve the matte effect more through how you "light" the object in photoshop, not as much through how you texture it. You need to add a gradient to your object, as well as some shadows, to give the appearance of a light source being diffused on its surface as opposed to being reflected harshly, as a glossy surface would.

Here is something I whipped up really quickly and you can see what I was doing, to accomplish it.  The banding in the gradient will need some cleaning up and there are other tutorials on how to achieve that, but this should get you started.

[image: results]

Settings:

[image: settings]

You can alternatively paint the gradient in using a large, soft brush.